# How to surface a value for more than one row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that I can surface a row in a query by using it in the `ORDER BY` like this :

```
SELECT IF(`category` IS NOT NULL,`category`,"Uncategorized") AS `category` FROM `table` ORDER BY `category`="Uncategorized" DESC
```

Which will make the first row always contain "Uncategorized", however I have multiple rows that contain it that I also want surfaced. Here are two sample sets of returned data:

What I'm getting:

```
Uncategorized
Science
Health
Uncategorized
Wellness
```

What I want:

```
Uncategorized
Uncategorized
Health
Science
Wellness
```

I have tried a number of other things including a `CASE` and also using a conditional `IF`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is not working is because the `ORDER BY` clause is comparing with the column name `category` and not on the alias given on the column.

```
SELECT IF(category IS NOT NULL,category,'Uncategorized') category
FROM   `table` 
ORDER  BY IF(category IS NOT NULL,category,'Uncategorized')='Uncategorized' DESC
```

you can alternatively use `COALESCE` or `IFNULL` to make it shorter

```
SELECT COALESCE(category, 'Uncategorized') category
FROM   `table` 
ORDER  BY COALESCE(category, 'Uncategorized') = 'Uncategorized' DESC, category
```

Comment: Awesome! Works great, I'm not sure why I thought the alias would be used. Also, I am curious at the performance difference of `COALESCE` VS the `IF` approach.

Comment: i think [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) is much faster.

Comment: also, because the optimizer finds the column name first and if it doesn't find it, it will go then on the alias.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the function in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT IF(`category` IS NOT NULL,`category`,"Uncategorized") AS `category`
  FROM `table`
  ORDER BY IF(`category` IS NOT NULL,`category`,"Uncategorized")="Uncategorized" DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ordering via [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

```
...
ORDER BY FIEID(category, 
    'Uncategorized',
    'Health',
    'Science'
    'Wellness')
```

The `FIELD()` function returns the index of the 1st parameter in the others.